# change font size of english words in a persian report

Tags: fontsize, xepersian

I am using `report` and `xepersian` packages to write a report in persian. I have some words and variables which are in english and use the `$example$` command to write them when they are inline.

How can I change the font size of these words?

Comment: `$...$` is for math!? But if it works for you, at least do `$\rm example$` or `$\text{example}$` to make it look good. To change the font size use `\footnotesize`, like `$\text{\footnotesize{example}}$`. Though im sure there is a real way of doing this.

Comment: @JonatanÖström when using the xepersian package, for words in english and math you should use `$...$`, I think there should be a better way than doing `$\text{\footnotesize{example}}$` for all those words.

Comment: But does it work or not? If it does, then you can make an alias like `\newcommand{\eng}[1]{$\text{\footnotesize{#1}}$` in the preamble and then only use \eng{example} throughout the document. (havent tried that though. May be a `\newenvironment` has to be created. In that case, google it and post your own solution here if you find one:)

Comment: @JonatanÖström It works in this way `\text{large{$example$}}`

Comment: So you have a solution now?

Comment: rather than `$english word$` use `\lr{english word}`

Answer (score 3):

You definitely should not use your English text using `$...$`. There are two proper ways to write English text in a Persian document:

a) If you only want to write a few word in a Persian and RTL paragraph, you should use `\lr{text}`:

```
سلام \lr{Hellp}  بازهم سلام
```

b) If you want to write a whole paragraph in English, and with LTR direction of course, you should use `latin` environment:

```
\begin{latin}
This is an english paragraph.
\end{latin}
```

Also, if your main language is English and you want to write Persian text somewhere, you should use `\rl` command and `persian` environment, respectively. For more info, please consult [`xepersian`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xepersian) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian/xepersian.pdf)

---

Now for the question of size, please consider these workarounds, in order:

a) Simply use latex font size commands whenever necessary:

```
\tiny
\scriptsize
\footnotesize
\small
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```

Consult [A (Not So) Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english) for more info.

b) If there is a non-coherency between your English and Persian font size, you can scale your Persian font size by `\settextfont` command:

```
\settextfont[Scale=0.8]{some font file...}
```

You can also do the same for Latin font as well:

```
\setlatintextfont[Scale=...]{...}
```